# Utilising controls (ComboBox) within Worksheet to control Auto filter

Tags: excel, vba

**Copying filtered data to another worksheet where user inputs filter criteria via ComboBox (userform or ActiveX)**

Ultimately, I want to copy out select data from a master data set on one worksheet to another worksheet. To isolate the relevant data for copying across I plan to use filters. I want to include a drop down list object within the worksheet that will allow the user to select the filter criteria

This is essentially just replicating the Excel data filter function but without being positionally restricted to the column being filtered.

I am assuming the Userform or ActiveX ComboBox is the way to achieve this? This where I'm failing. I can't figure out how to call the value selected from the ComboBox by the user to inform the AutoFilter procedure.

```
Sub M_00()

    Dim wB As Workbook
    Dim wS1, wS2 As Worksheet
    'Dim x As ???
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim lrowS3 As Long

    Set wB = This.Workbook
    Set wS1 = wB.Sheets(1)
    Set wS3 = wB.Sheets(3)

    'define range for Combo Box drop down list from data on Sheet 3
    lrowS3 = wS3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng3 = wS3.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lrowS3, 2))

    'Don't know how to
    ' a) assign my rng3 values to the ComboBox drop down list
    ' b) call the selection from the ComboBox to inform my AutoFilter

    wS1.ComboBox1.List = rng3.Value

    x = wS1.ComboBox1.Selection

    ' turn off any autofilters that may already be active in Sheet 1
    wS1.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' filter column 4 based on combo box selection
    wS1.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=x

    'Once filtered I plan you assign the visible data to an array and copy 
    'it to the required sheet.
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that if you `Dim wS1, wS2 As Worksheet` only `wS2` is of type `Worksheet` but `wS1` is `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim wS1 As Worksheet, wS2 As Worksheet` otherwise it defaults to  `Variant`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. May I ask where your code is located? Is it in a module? Is it in a worksheet object? Is it in a userform?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I didn't realize that. Code is located in module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up splitting the operation into two modules, M_00_Filter() and M_00_Generate().

The first filters the data based on the selection from a user form combobox statically assigned a range from another worksheet in the same workbook.

```
Sub M_00_Filter()

Dim wB As Workbook
Dim myindex As Long
Dim filterValue As String
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim rng2BF As Range

Set wB = ThisWorkbook
Set wS = wB.Sheets("Master Schedule")

'~~> Currently selected item index at runtime
myindex = wS.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.Value

'~~> Currently selected item value at runtime
filterValue = wS.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.List(myindex)

lRow = wS.Cells(wS.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = wS.Cells(5, wS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Set rngToBeFiltered
Set rng2BF = wS.Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(lRow, lCol))

If filterValue = "Select a Phase" Then

    rng2BF.AutoFilter field:=4 'If No Filter is selected then all data is displayed

Else

    rng2BF.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=filterValue 'else the filter is applied

End If

End Sub
```

The second module copies the visible data and copies it out to another workbook.
Thanks again for your help.

Appreciate you all taking the time. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what an autofilter does is that it hides the entirerows that dont match the selection right. In this example, I'll asume the info you are looking for if in column B

```
'getting the value I am looking for
  cbVal = comboBox1.Text

 'getting the last row filled
 lr = activesheet.cells(rows.count,2).end(xlup).row


'asuming that B1 is the title of the table, so I'm starting since B2 to last row

for i = 2 to lr
if not activesheet.range("B"&i) == cbVal then
  activesheet.range("B"&i).entireRow.Hidden = true
end if
next i
```

Finally, yo set anothe sub for unhiding the rows

```
for i = 2 to lr
activesheet.range("B"&i).hidden = false
next i
```

Hope it has solved your problem, I haven't tested yer but the ideas is that you get the logics

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure I get 100% what you're trying to do, but here's one way to do it:

The following approach is meant to work with an ActiveX combobox.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume you have the following setup:

[image]

The filter values are in `A1:A8` and you want to filter column C, by the name of day.

Firstly, you need a sub that initializes the combobox. This can be located in your module. How this `sub` is called is up to you. If the list needs to be updated regularly you could have a dedicated button for this.

```
Sub initializeComboBox() 'The name of the Sub is self explanatory

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet") 'The worksheet where the combobox is located
With sht.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object 'Referring to the combobox from outside the worksheet where it's located can be a bit tricky
    .Clear 'Clear the combobox's list
    .List = sht.Range("A1:A8").Value 'assign the values contained in range A1:A8 to the combobox's list
End With

End Sub
```

Then you need an event that will capture the change of the combobox's value whenever the user selects one. This needs to be located in the worksheet to which the combobox belongs.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change() 'This event fires up whenever the user selects an item from the dropdown menu
Dim x As String
x = ComboBox1.Value 'referring to the combobox from inside the worksheet where it belongs is easier
Module1.testFilter (x)
End Sub
```

Then you could either have a `sub` that is located in your module and is being called by this event, or you could just do anything you want to, using the event itself. I applied the first approach here but it's really your choice.

```
Sub testFilter(filterValue As String) 'A sub that is located in the module and applies the filter. This is called whenever the Value of the combobox is changed

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rngToBeFiltered As Range
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet") 'The worksheet where the range that needs to be filtered is located
Set rngToBeFiltered = sht.Columns("C")
If filterValue = "No Filter" Then
    rngToBeFiltered.AutoFilter field:=1 'If No Filter is selected then all data is displayed
Else
    rngToBeFiltered.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=filterValue 'else the filter is applied
End If

End Sub
```

The result would like that:

[image]